# Decode and update the image attribute - carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Save the decoded image in AWS path, I am using carrierwave gem

I have a base64 encoded image in my controller. I would like to decode the image and want to save the reference in database and Save the image in AWS server

In my model I have the decoding and assigning option like this. But I am Unable to save the image parameter in database. **I am getting error unpermitted parameter image.** But I have included it in strong parameters

```
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  def decode_base64_image(encoded_file)
    decoded_file = Base64.decode64(encoded_file)
    file = Tempfile.new(['image','.png'])
    file.binmode
    file.write decoded_file

    self.image = file

  end


class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the error message? Can you please add the code of `ImageUploader` class?

Comment: The Uploader looks fine. Since the problem is with the unpermitted parameter, can you show the controller (for strong params)? Or just put a binding pry in a method that checks params :)